# Lynis Indicates Compilers

Tags: audit, compiler

On a droplet, when Lynis reports that compilers have been found, I've been unable to determine which compilers it means exactly. I'd like to remove these. How can I?

There is another thread, but the "how to find which compilers it's talking about" isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler checks are performed in the test `HRDN-7220` which is defined in the include/tests_hardening file.

The tests itself are performed by the include/binaries file and the variable `COMPILER_INSTALLED` is set when the following files are found within the `$PATH` variable:

- as
- g++
- gcc

So in short, when Lynis reports that compilers are installed, you have to check the above three files within the PATH directories.